# Getting data from 3 MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I'm having a struggle here trying to grab some data from 3 database tables..

The idea is that users can fill out their profile with several fields, and I'm storing every profile field, field values and the users selected value in separate tables.

The structure of the tables look like this:

```
Table 'profile_fields'
- id
- name
- sort
- status (enum '0', '1')

Table 'profile_field_values'
- id
- profile_field_id
- name

Table 'user_profile_fields'
- user_id
- profile_field_id
- profile_field_value_id
```

Would be really nice if you could tell me how to construct this query, and why you used the JOIN you did.

Also, how would this table layout scale when the userbase grows?

Thank you so much in advance!

Edit:
OK, I still can't figure out how to make it return all the fields from 'profile_fields' along with the users selected option from 'user_profile_fields'. If the user hasn't selected a value, it should just be null.

This is my (non-functional) query so far:

```
SELECT  PF.id AS field_id, PF.name AS field_name, UPF.profile_field_value_id AS value_id, PF.type, PFV.name 
FROM  profile_fields  PF
LEFT JOIN profile_fields_values PFV ON PFV.profile_field_id = PF.id
LEFT JOIN user_profile_fields UPF ON UPF.user_id=1  AND PF.id = UPF.profile_field_id
WHERE length(PF.name) > 0 and PF.status = '1'
ORDER BY PF.sort
```

This query seems to work, but it does not fetch the name of the value from 'profile_field_values':

```
SELECT PF.id AS field_id, PF.name AS field_name, UPF.profile_field_value_id AS value_id, PF.type
FROM profile_fields PF
LEFT JOIN user_profile_fields UPF ON UPF.user_id =1
AND PF.id = UPF.profile_field_id
WHERE LENGTH( PF.name ) >0
AND PF.status =  '1'
ORDER BY PF.sort
```

Comment: `I'm having a struggle here trying to grab some data from 3 database tables.` And what have you tried while struggling, update your question with some of your code.

Comment: side note, be careful using numbers in ENUM. Make sure your queries for enum are quoted correctly.

Comment: @James, yeah, I found out about that. At first I received an error for not quoting the value. Thanks :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems like simple JOINs should work:

```
SELECT pf.id, pf.name, pf.sort, pf.status,
    pfv.id, pfv.profile_field_id, pfv.name,
    upf.user_id, upf.profile_field_id, upf.profile_field_value_id
FROM profile_fields pf
    INNER JOIN profile_field_values pfv 
        ON pf.id = pfv.profile_field_id
    INNER JOIN user_profile_fields upf 
        ON upf.profile_field_value_id = pfv.id AND upf.profile_field_id = pf.id
```

[A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

This uses an `INNER JOIN` to select all matching records from each table -- review the post to tell the difference between an `INNER` and an `OUTER` join.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I know that method of explaining joins, but last time I consulted it, I didn't seem to get it, but I guess I can give it another try :-) However, I was trying to get this to work with LEFT JOIN. That wouldn't work? Again, thanks a bunch!

Comment: @user1169875 -- you can definitely use an `OUTER JOIN` (`LEFT JOIN`) -- just replace the `INNER JOIN`.  That will return all records from the `profile_fields` table even if there aren't matches from the other two tables.  Best of luck!

Comment: @user1169875 -- np, glad it helped. Cheers!

Comment: Hey again, I just tried replacing INNER with LEFT in this section: `INNER JOIN profile_field_values pfv`, to get the field name for all fields, but it still just returns the matching rows only. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @user1169875 -- try replacing both `INNER` joins with `LEFT` joins, not just the one.

Comment: I tried that and then it returns every each one of the value options. Would be nice if I could fetch all the names from 'profile_fields' even if the user hasn't chosen one, to output them all in my template.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some unnecessary complexity in there. Maybe you should try

Table 'profile_fields'

- id
- name
- sort
- status (enum '0', '1')

Table 'profile_field_values'

- id
- user_id
- profile_field_id
- value

why are there 3 tables?

Comment: Hi there. I did that to be able to easily add new selectable values. Those values will be put in some selectboxes for the users to choose from :-)